# Poetry sees an indirect dependency (numpy for python) is outdated, but doesn't update it

Tags: python-poetry

Trying out poetry 1.1.11 and have pandas in my pyproject.toml in the tool.poetry.dependencies section.  Pandas depends on numpy

```
pandas 1.3.3 Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
├── numpy >=1.17.3
├── python-dateutil >=2.7.3
│   └── six >=1.5 
└── pytz >=2017.3
```

When I called `poetry add pandas` it correctly installed numpy 1.21.1.  Numpy has bumped to 1.22.2 and poetry recognizes this

```
poetry show --outdated
numpy 1.21.1 1.21.2 NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
```

But numpy isn't updated by poetry.

```
poetry update
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.3s)

No dependencies to install or update
```

Is this expected?  How / when would numpy be updated?

EDIT2:  per @finswimmer's request, here's the TOML and for a simpler case than in the first EDIT TOML.  It's an empty project from `poetry new`.  Then try `poetry add numpy` as below.

Just

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "delete_me4"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

```
❯ poetry add numpy
Using version ^1.21.2 for numpy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.0s)

  SolverProblemError

  The current project's Python requirement (>=3.9,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - numpy requires Python >=3.7,<3.11, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.11,<4.0
  
  Because numpy (1.21.2) requires Python >=3.7,<3.11
   and no versions of numpy match >1.21.2,<2.0.0, numpy is forbidden.
  So, because delete-me4 depends on numpy (^1.21.2), version solving failed.

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│ 
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties
    
    For numpy, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.9,<3.11"

    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies,
    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers
```

Comment: Most probably you have another dependency that depends on numpy <1.22. Could you post your full `pyproject.toml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suggestion in the help text above addresses the issue.  `poetry add numpy` works in an empty project with this TOML change.

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9,<3.11"
```

I'm not sure what triggered it wanting Python >= 3.11 descoped, but hey.  It solved the problem for me once I tried the repro.

Note that constraining Python further as follows allows for scipy to move from 1.6.1 to 1.7.1

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9,<3.10"
```